# Console Error : Invalid Firebase Data setvalue cannot store object

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3, firebase-storage

I'm a total beginner in xcode 8 and swift and encountered this error below in my console, please help me

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at profileImageUrl. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'**

This is my code,

```
let uid = user?.user.uid
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://instagramclone-7713a.appspot.com").child("profile_image").child(uid!)
            if let profileImg = self.selectedImage, let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImg, 0.1) {
                storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                    if (error != nil) {
                        return
                    }

                    let profileImageUrl = storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { url, error in

                    })

                    let ref = Database.database().reference()
                    let usersReference = ref.child("users")
                    let newUserReference = usersReference.child(uid!)
                    newUserReference.setValue(["username": self.UsernameTextField.text!, "email": self.emailTextField.text!, "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl])
                })
            }

        })

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `setValue()` inside the completion block of `downloadURL()`.

```
storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { url, error in
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let usersReference = ref.child("users")
    let newUserReference = usersReference.child(uid!)
    newUserReference.setValue(["username": self.UsernameTextField.text!, "email": self.emailTextField.text!, "profileImageUrl": url])
})
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but sadly it’s still not working; my app still crashed. I have a thread 1 sigabrt in appdelegate in code ( ‘class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {‘ )